# Create function which only starts after a specific tab bar is changed

Tags: ios, swift3

I have been trying to make a function start after specific tab bar is changed.

My problem is that I am making a movie app and in one of the tab bars you can choose which genres you want the app to search for. However I need to update the request string when the user switches from the genreselector to another tab bar like settings or the movie finder tab bar.

I have looked at using a tab bar controller but i can only see if the user cliked on one of the tab bars and not see when they specifically change from the genreSelector to another tab view item.

Would love if someone could point me in the right direction :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can implement the `tabBarControllerDelegate` method:

```
func tabBarController(UITabBarController, shouldSelect: UIViewController)
```

It's called when a specific `UIViewController` is selected. If the view controller that should be selected is not `genreSelector` you can go ahead and update the request string.

Comment: Thank you, I will try this later today :)